# Google font link is returning a 403 error, how can I resolve this?

Tags: http-status-code-403, google-fonts

I've inherited a website here which has a 403 error loading fonts. The specific font is bookman old style. It still displays in chrome and firefox, but not in safari.

https://bmdrivingschool.ca

This is the code in the head which as far as I can tell is correct to not have http or https, and the link does load if I add https to it.

`<link rel="stylesheet" id="cherry-google-fonts-css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat%3A700%2Cregular%7CBookman+Old+Style%3A700%7CAbril+Fatface%3Aregular&amp;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&amp;ver=5.0.3" type="text/css" media="all">`

any help would be appreciated greatly, probably something simple I have not thought of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<link id="cherry-google-fonts-css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat%3A700%2Cregular%7CBookman+Old+Style%3A700%7CAbril+Fatface%3Aregular&amp;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&amp;ver=5.0.3" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide a bit more explanation.

Comment: thanks but I tried this and it still isn't loading the font in safari